# Get All Controls of winform?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, forms

I have a form with many table layout panel, Group Box and Flow Layout Panel, One inside another. I have set a string value to the Tag of each Textbox, label and some controls.
 How can i get all the controls where tag value is string ?
 [image: My Form With Controls]

Comment: The word you're look for is `recursion`.

Comment: How to use that, because each Panel has its on type of ContainerContols ?

Comment: I have made an [API Proposal: Add Descendants property for Control](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/5195) on github.com/dotnet/winforms for this. If you like it, please upvote it there.

Answer (score 0):

The form's Controls property is an Array of all controls reside in the form.
At the same way, each Container control, like Panels, TabControl, etch. Has it's own Controls property.
So you can use a statement like this:

```
Dim Control As Windows.Forms.Control
For Each Control In Me.Controls
'Your logic Here  

If Control.GetType Is GetType(System.windows.Forms.Panel) Or ... 'Any Other Container Type control
Dim Nested As Windows.Forms.Control
For Each Nested In Control... 'Your logic Here
End
```